# Django - django-admin-tools

Tags: django, django-admin

I have just installed django-admin-tools app. But I can't able to move "Quick links" box to anywhere. Is there any way to the 'Quick links' box to the right side of admin interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just followed this documentation.

http://packages.python.org/django-admin-tools/0.3.0/customization.html#customizing-the-dashboards